# flutter - update or remove stateFullWidget in ListWidgets

Tags: jquery, flutter, provider, statefulwidget

in my case i have stateFulwidget that will handle move,rotate and scale of widget
i have map<String,Widget> ... after move or action in screen i will update the stateFulwidget as set new info's on that
**what is the problem**
list Widgets from Map working fine until i just creating and adding stateFulwidget into List
but if i want to remove or update the stateFullWidget in List will not work

im confused! i dont know why and what is the problem in case
please help and give me some idea for resolve this
Thank you

*the provider Class*

```
class ProviderStoryCustomText with ChangeNotifier {
  Map<String, Map<String, dynamic>> textsMapInfo = {};
  Map<String, Widget> listWidgets = {};

  void setTextInfo({
    required List<Color> screenColorsList,
    required double screenWidth,
    required String textID,
    required String text,
    required Color color,
    required Color backGroundColor,
    required int backGroundStatus,
    required int alignStatus,
    required String? fontFamily,
    required int? fontSelectedIndex,
    required double? positionY,
    required double? positionL,
    required double rotate,
    required double scale,
  }) {
    String iD = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
    
    textsMapInfo[iD] = {
      'textID': iD,
      'text': text,
      'color': color,
      'backGroundColor': backGroundColor,
      'textBackGroundStatus': backGroundStatus,
      'alignStatus': alignStatus,
      'fontFamily': fontFamily,
      'fontSelectedIndex': fontSelectedIndex,
      'positionY': positionY,
      'positionL': positionL,
      'rotate': rotate,
      'scale': scale,
    };

    add(textID, iD, screenWidth, screenColorsList);
  }

  void add(String textID, String iD, double screenWidth,
      List<Color> screenColorsList) {
    // listWidgets = {};
    if (listWidgets.containsKey(textID)) {
      listWidgets.update(
          textID,
          (value) =>
              // Text("aaa")
              CustomStoryText(
                  textInfo: textsMapInfo[textID],
                  screenWidth: screenWidth,
                  screenColorsList: screenColorsList));
    } else {
      listWidgets[iD] =
          // Text("${textID}");
          CustomStoryText(
              textInfo: textsMapInfo[iD],
              screenWidth: screenWidth,
              screenColorsList: screenColorsList);
    }
    print("UPDAAATE");
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

*i pass widgets and list into Stack *
also we can create some of this widgets

```
Stack(
       fit: StackFit.expand,
       children: ctx.watch<ProviderStoryCustomText>().listWidgets.values.toList(),
      )
```

*and at the end my customTextStory Constractor*

```
class CustomStoryImage extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomStoryImage({
    Key? key,
    required this.imgFile,
    required this.screenHeight,
    required this.screenWidth,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final File imgFile;
  final double? screenWidth;
  final double? screenHeight;

  @override
  State<CustomStoryImage> createState() => _CustomStoryImageState();
}

class _CustomStoryImageState extends State<CustomStoryImage> {...}
```

Comment: your providers should only keep some data, not widgets - you should create widgets in your UI layer only, and then if you have any problems with widget updating most likely you need to use widget keys - for more check [when to use keys](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc) short presentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @pskink
as you said the solution it is
for managing stateFulwidgets have you pass them `key: UniqueKey(),`

the uniqueKey work as well for each statefulWidget

if you want have multi of them in your list also you can update,remove them as well

Thank you again @pslink for Helping to solve this question

on this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=kn0EOS-ZiIc) flutter team will explain complitly